# Is it a must to use spring-data-jdbc when using JdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-data-jdbc

I am planning to use Spring `JdbcTemplate` to access my database. Is it a must to use spring-data-jdbc when using `JdbcTemplate`? The reason I am asking is I don't need "entity"(POJO) for my table in my application. Would it add some overheads if I use spring-data-jdbc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `JdbcTemplate` without Spring Data JDBC without a problem.
`JdbcTemplate` existed for many years before Spring Data JDBC was conceived.

Spring Data JDBC does involve an overhead.
It extracts data from POJOs, creates queries and transforms the result back to POJOs. 
Of course all that takes resources. 
If you don't need/benefit from it don't use it.

You can also start with `JdbcTemplate` and later start using Spring Data JDBC without a problem if the need arises.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need some advises. My application generates csv files from the database via a web service endpoint. Can you think of any benefits of using spring-data-jdbc?

Comment: So basically one select per file and dump out the result with some delimiters? Sounds like a case for pure `JdbcTemplate` to me.

Answer (score 1):

`JdbcTemplate` is part of the [spring-jdbc](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate) module, so you only need that (and sprint-tx, which includes the `DataAccessException` hierarchy).

spring-**data**-jdbc adds support for (not surprisingly) [spring-data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data) on top of spring-jdbc. So you don't need it to use `JdbcTemplate`, the same as you don't need spring-data-jpa to use the JPA `EntityManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-data-jdbc is implemented on the basis of spring-jdbc. If you don't need Entity at all, then using spring-jdbc to interact directly with the database is the most convenient and flexible. In this case, using spring-data-jdbc is just a pure increase in learning costs. Spring-data-jdbc is designed for DDD (Domain Driven Design) mode, which is different from the current mainstream programming model. The learning cost is not low...